# The movie clips still appear on the next scene what is wrong with my code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Every time you drag and drop an incorrect box onto the target_mc, the box shows up on the next scene and doesnt go away why is this?  Thanks very much for the help.  The code is actionscript 3 and the app is being made in adobe animate.  The box does not got away at any point in the app unless it is restarted.

```
stop();



import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

/* Touch and Drag Event
Allows the object to be moved by holding and dragging the object.
*/
var objectoriginalXX:Number;
var objectoriginalYY:Number;



var countApple:int = 0;


Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

var apples:Array = [apple1_mc, apple2_mc, apple3_mc, apple4_mc, apple5_mc];

for each(var appleMC:MovieClip in apples)
{
appleMC.buttonMode = true;
appleMC.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, pickobject1);
appleMC.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, dropobject1);

appleMC.startX = appleMC.x;
appleMC.startY = appleMC.y;

}
var fl_DragBounds1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);


function pickobject1(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, fl_DragBounds1);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    objectoriginalXX = event.target.x; 
    objectoriginalYY = event.target.y;


}

function dropobject1(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    if(event.target.hitTestObject(target_mc)){
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = target_mc.x;
        event.target.y = target_mc.y;
        event.target.visible = false;
        wellsound.play();
        countApple ++;


    }

    if(countApple == 5)
    {

    gotoAndPlay(4072);


    }


else{
    event.target.x = event.target.startX;
    event.target.y = event.target.startY;
    event.target.buttonMode = true;
}


}

nexthomeBtn12.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,onTouchBeginhomescene12);


function onTouchBeginhomescene12 (e:TouchEvent):void{

gotoAndPlay(0);
SoundMixer.stopAll();


}




var peachs:Array = [peach1_mc, peach2_mc, peach3_mc, peach4_mc, peach5_mc, peach6_mc];
for each(var peachMC:MovieClip in peachs)
{
peachMC.buttonMode = true;
peachMC.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, pickobject3);
peachMC.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, dropobject3);

peachMC.startX = peachMC.x;
peachMC.startY = peachMC.y;

}
var fl_DragBounds3:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);


function pickobject3(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, fl_DragBounds3);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    objectoriginalXX = event.target.x; 
    objectoriginalYY = event.target.y;


}

function dropobject3(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    if(event.target.hitTestObject(target_null)){
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = target_mc.x;
        event.target.y = target_mc.y;
        event.target.visible = false;


    }



    else{
    event.target.x = event.target.startX;
    event.target.y = event.target.startY;
    event.target.buttonMode = true;
    trysound.play();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because scene is not a separate object (like **Sprite** or **MovieClip**). For the Flash Player scene is just a logical portion of frames (for the sake of backward compatibility and because designers/animators tend to think in terms *Scene 1, frame 10*) on the main timeline (while the whole main timeline is a **MovieClip**), thus you add a child to it and it will persist no mater how you **gotoAndPlay** to and fro.

Mixing programming and long timelines is generally a bad idea.

Thus, to fix it without spilling lots of blood, you need to keep track of all the things you've added with **addChild** and **removeChild** each of them respectively.

Or, alternately, work in some container, not main timeline. When you go to other frame, the container will not persist, and all its content will be destroyed as well.